# Equality of dependent types and dependent values

Tags: equality, coq, dependent-type

Consider a dependent type

```
Inductive dep (n: nat) :=
  mkDep : dep n.
```

Now, consider a simple theorem I wish to prove:

```
Theorem equalTypes (n n': nat): n = n' -> dep n = dep n'.
Proof.
  intros.
Abort.
```

How do I show that two dependent types are equal? What is a notion of type equality?

Worse, consider this "theorem" (which does not compile)

```
Theorem equalInhabitants (n n' : nat): n = n' -> mkDep n = mkDep n'.
Abort.
```

This very **statement** is wrong, because the types `mkDep n` and `mkDep n'` don't match. However, in some sense, this statement is **true**, because they *are* the same value under the assumption `n = n'`.

I wish to understand how to formalize and prove statements about dependent types (specifically, their equality and notions thereof)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I show that two dependent types are equal?

In this case, you can prove it with `apply f_equal; assumption` or `subst; reflexivity` (or `destruct H; reflexivity` or `case H; reflexivity` or `induction H; reflexivity` or `exact (eq_rect n (fun n' => dep n = dep n') eq_refl n' H)`).

> What is a notion of type equality?

The same as any other equality; `Print eq.` gives:

```
Inductive eq (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Prop :=  eq_refl : x = x
```

which says that the only special fact you have to construct a proof of equality is that `x = x` for any `x`.  The way to use a proof of equality, `eq_rect`, is that, if you have `x = y`, to prove a property `P` of `y`, it suffices to prove `P` of `x`.  In this case, since we have `n = n'`, to prove `dep n = dep n'`, it suffices to prove `dep n = dep n` (where `P := fun n' => dep n = dep n'`).

There is a deeper sense in which this question can be asked, because it turns out that equality of types in Coq is under-constrained.  Given

```
Inductive unit1 := tt1.
Inductive unit2 := tt2.
```

you can not prove `unit1 = unit2`, nor can you prove `unit1 <> unit2`.  In fact, it turns out that the only type inequalities `T1 <> T2` that you can prove are cases where you can prove that `T1` and `T2` are not isomorphic.  The Univalence axiom is a way of "filling in the details" of type equality to say that any isomorphic types are equal.  There are other consistent interpretations, though (for example, I believe that it's consistent to assume `A * B = C * D -> A = C /\ B = D`, though this contradicts univalence).

> Worse, consider this "theorem" (which does not compile)
>
> ```
> Theorem equalInhabitants (n n' : nat): n = n' -> mkDep n = mkDep n'.
> ```

Right.  This is because we do not have an equality reflection rule in Coq, and judgmental/definitional equality is not the same as propositional equality.  The way to state this is to "cast" the term `mkDep n` across the proof of equality.

```
Import EqNotations.
Theorem equalInhabitants (n n' : nat): forall H : n = n', rew H in mkDep n = mkDep n'.
  intros.
  subst; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Note that `rew` binds more tightly than `=`, and is a notation for `eq_rect`.  This says that for any proof `H` of `n = n'`, the term `mkDep n`, when transported across `H` to become a term of type `dep n'`, is equal to `mkDep n'`.  (Note also that we could just as well have used `destruct H` or `induction H` or `case H` (but not `apply f_equal`) instead of `subst`.)